# Not able to clear Text Field in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

HTML code of elements is as -

```
<input cascadechildren="" class="form-control yearMonthDayFocus cascadeParent hasDatepicker" id="StartDate_10" name="StartDate_10" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" value="20-10-2020">
```

I've used below statements.

```
Input Text    [LOC]  ${EMPTY}
Press Keys  [LOC]  CTRL+a+BACKSPACE
Clear Element Text
Press Keys  [LOC]  /BACKSPACE
```

Please let me know if you have different answers

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: It is working fine with following code,

`Clear Element Text    StartDate_10`

Answer (score 3):

You aren't telling it which element to clear. [Clear element text](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Clear%20Element%20Text) requires a locator.  For example:

```
Clear Element Text  id:StartDate_10
```